# Cloudinary stuck on Displacement

Tags: cloudinary

I am trying to generate a mockup for t-shirts.

The result I am trying to achieve is the following: https://prnt.sc/kzhjk7

Using cloudinary, this is the closest result I have been able to produce:

https://res.cloudinary.com/worldwide-buy-llc/image/upload/c_scale,o_0,w_380/a_0,c_scale,l_TemplateSquare,r_0,w_380,x_900,y_190/c_scale,l_TemplateSquare,w_380,x_-310,y_240/c_scale,u_Mockups:Kids_White,w_3623,x_0,y_0/c_scale,l_Mockups:Kids_Whiteover,o_100,w_3623,x_0/v1538036215/TemplateSquare.png

However, it still looks different from the image that I would like to achieve.

I read that I could apply displacement. For this reason, I do have a displacement map stored at Mockups:Kids_WhiteOver

Do you know how can I apply it? Also the colors of the layers TemplateSquare appear weak in comparison to the target result ( https://prnt.sc/kzhjk7 ). 
Any suggestion is very much appreciated since I am literally stuck to achieve that result. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try using the e_displace. For example:
https://res.cloudinary.com/worldwide-buy-llc/image/upload/o_0/l_TemplateSquare,w_380,y_300,x_-450/l_TemplateSquare,w_380,y_100,x_650/l_Mockups:Kids_Whiteover,e_displace,x_10,y_10/l_Mockups:Kids_Whiteover,e_displace,x_10,y_10/u_Mockups:kids_white/l_Mockups:Kids_Whiteover,o_29/TemplateSquare.png let me know your thought :)

Comment: Hi Shirly,

first of all, many thanks for your help! :)

It looks different from the desired result since the colors are too weak and regarding the displacement, the effect should be similar to this: https://prnt.sc/kzhjk7 .
Do you know how can I achieve it?

Comment: How about this one:
https://res.cloudinary.com/shirly/image/upload/o_0/l_TemplateSquare,w_380,y_300,x_-450/l_TemplateSquare,w_380,y_100,x_650/l_Kids_Whiteover,e_displace,x_10,y_10/u_kids_white,e_multiply/TemplateSquare.png Let me know if that can works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the opacity from the transformation and use the multiplying effect. 
How about this one: https://res.cloudinary.com/shirly/image/upload/o_0/l_TemplateSquare,w_380,y_300,x_-450/l_TemplateSquare,w_380,y_100,x_650/l_Kids_Whiteover,e_displace,x_10,y_10/u_kids_white,e_multiply/TemplateSquare.png

Let me know if that result can work for you.